# Sqliteのsumifs類似文で、結果が0以上の値のみ表示したい

Tags: sqlite

sqliteでexcelのsumifsに類似する方法を探してきました。

```
SELECT Date,

IfNULL(sum(CASE WHEN country = 'Japan'  AND Category = 'Export' THEN 金額 END),0) [ExportToJapan],

FROM Sales
GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY Date
```

この方法では、ExportToJapanの値が0の日付も表示されてしまいます。

```
WHERE ExportToJapan > 0
```

文を
    GROUP BY Date
    ORDER BY Date
の前後に入れてみたのですがSytax Errorになってしまいます。

よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

例えば、こんな感じで、どうでしょう？

```
SELECT Date, ExportToJapan from (
    SELECT Date,
        IfNULL(sum(CASE WHEN country = 'Japan' AND Category = 'Export' THEN 金額 END), 0) [ExportToJapan]
    FROM Sales
    GROUP BY Date
    ORDER BY Date)
WHERE ExportToJapan >= 0
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。